# Emmet intellisense not showing

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

I just created a new react application and all of a sudden Emmet doesn't work, but ONLY in this project.

If I type "div*2", intellisense popout doesn't show up. But if I go to edit menu and click "Emmet: Expand abbreviation" it does exactly what it's supposed to do and generates two divs.

I only have 2 extensions running, I disabled both and no difference. Works great in other projects.

Comment: what is the languageID of the file, you can add other laguageID's

Comment: languageID is javascript. Emmet: Include Languages is empty, but it's also empty in other projects where Emmet intellisense works properly.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_emmet-abbreviations-in-other-file-types